# React Strictmode preventing a custom made useState hook to change the state at the first call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I was following along a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jWS7cCuUXw) of Ryan florence (creator of remix and ReactTraining.com). There he was demistifying **useState** hook, by making one of his own.
I followed along the procedure, and implemented this in a component.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



function MadeUseStateMyself() {
  const [minutes,setMinutes] = useState(5)
  const [error,setError] = useState(null)
  
  const handleAdd = () => {
      if(minutes<9){
          setMinutes(minutes+1)
          setError(null)
      }
      else{
          setError('Less than 10 please')
      }
  }
  const handleSubStract = () => {
    if(minutes>0){
        setMinutes(minutes-1)
        setError(null)
    }
    else{
        setError('More than 0 please')
    }
}

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={handleSubStract} > - </button>
        <p>{minutes}</p>
        <button onClick={handleAdd} > + </button>
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
const states = []
let calls = -1
const useState = def => {
    const callId = ++calls
    if(states[callId]) {
        return states[callId]
    }
    const setDef = newV => {
       states[callId][0] = newV
       reRender()
    }
    const state = [def,setDef]
    states.push(state)
    return state
}
function reRender(){
    calls = -1
    ReactDOM.render(<MadeUseStateMyself/>,document.getElementById('root'))
}
export default MadeUseStateMyself
```

Here I noticed a really peculiar behavior, that is, whenever I use **React.StrictMode** wrapping my entire component, the state doesnt change after the first function call(In this case, I implemented an incremental and a decremental button which changes the state of one singular integer state.) 
This problem doesnt rise if I get rid of the **React.StrictMode** wrapper.
Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cloud-ttsp0y?file=/src/MadeUseStateMyself.jsx&fbclid=IwAR2fimkaAVgISp07wacNZC3TM-YCNMRukS-PivTnF-XxRs5PbUQ0lrzC5_E)

Reading the [StrictMode docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) , one of my assumptions is that as in strictmode, function component bodies are invoked twice, it loses its first state during the second function call, thus losing the first change of state. 
Am I even close?

Comment: `React.StrictMode` intentionally calls your components twice to make sure you're not doing anything silly. An imperfect custom implementation (where that `calls` counter isn't aware of `StrictMode`)  of `setState` is likely to be considered silly.

Comment: @AKX thanks for answering. I edited the question a bit, can you please check out the last paragraph and tell me that whether my thoughts align yours?

Comment: I really don't have much to add here – your custom hook does things that aren't quite safe with strict mode off (since internally React doesn't e.g. guarantee it always renders everything in the same order) and in strict mode, things just outright break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to watch about 13 minutes into the video to spot the first difference between your code and that in the demo. The presenter said to immediately manually invoke the custom `reRender` function to do the initial render. It's from here I noticed that you were rendering your app twice. `MadeUseStateMyself` is rendered once in the custom `reRender` function and is also exported and rendered again into the DOM in the `index.js` file.

You've effectively two instances of your `MadeUseStateMyself` component rendered as a React stomping on each other.

If you take your code and immediately invoke `reRender`, and also completely remove the `index.js` rendering code, while *also* wrapping `MadeUseStateMyself` in a `React.StrictMode` component, you'll see it has no issues rendering and updating.

MadeUseStateMyself

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const states = [];
let calls = -1;

const useState = (def) => {
  const callId = ++calls;
  if (states[callId]) {
    return states[callId];
  }
  const setDef = (newV) => {
    states[callId][0] = newV;
    reRender();
  };
  const state = [def, setDef];
  states.push(state);
  return state;
};

function MadeUseStateMyself() {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(5);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    if (minutes < 9) {
      setMinutes(minutes + 1);
      setError(null);
    } else {
      setError("Less than 10 please");
    }
  };

  const handleSubStract = () => {
    if (minutes > 0) {
      setMinutes(minutes - 1);
      setError(null);
    } else {
      setError("More than 0 please");
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={handleSubStract}> - </button>
      <p>{minutes}</p>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}> + </button>
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function reRender() {
  calls = -1;
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode> // <-- add the React.StrictMode
      <MadeUseStateMyself />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

reRender(); // <-- Invoke immediately
```

[image: Edit react-strictmode-preventing-a-custom-made-usestate-hook-to-change-the-state-at-t]